# How to show a descriptive column on line wrap but hide it between tables with css?

Tags: css, html-table, css-float

Is it possible, to show a desciptive column to data, if it is the leftmost table, but not show it, if it is to the right of another table by just using html and css?

Something like this:

```css
table {
        margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
        float: left;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td class="description">
        Descriptive Row 1 of Table 1
    </td>
    <td class="data">
        Content Row 1 of Table 1
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="description">
        Descriptive Row 2 of Table 1
    </td>
    <td class="data">
        Content Row 2 of Table 1
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="description">
        Descriptive Row n of Table 1
    </td>
    <td class="data">
        Content Row n of Table 1
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td class="description">
        Descriptive Row 1 of Table 2
    </td>
    <td class="data">
        Content Row 1 of Table 2
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="description">
        Descriptive Row 2 of Table 2
    </td>
    <td class="data">
        Content Row 2 of Table 2
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="description">
        Descriptive Row n of Table 2
    </td>
    <td class="data">
        Content Row n of Table 2
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td class="description">
        Descriptive Row 1 of Table 3
    </td>
    <td class="data">
        Content Row 1 of Table 3
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="description">
        Descriptive Row 2 of Table 3
    </td>
    <td class="data">
        Content Row 2 of Table 3
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="description">
        Descriptive Row n of Table 3
    </td>
    <td class="data">
        Content Row n of Table 3
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Shown like this:

```
+------------------------------+--------------------------++--------------------------+
| Descriptive Row 1 of Table 1 | Content Row 1 of Table 1 || Content Row 1 of Table 2 |
+------------------------------+--------------------------++--------------------------+
| Descriptive Row 2 of Table 1 | Content Row 2 of Table 1 || Content Row 2 of Table 2 |
+------------------------------+--------------------------++--------------------------+
| Descriptive Row n of Table 1 | Content Row n of Table 1 || Content Row n of Table 2 |
+------------------------------+--------------------------++--------------------------+

+------------------------------+--------------------------+
| Descriptive Row 1 of Table 3 | Content Row 1 of Table 3 |
+------------------------------+--------------------------+
| Descriptive Row 2 of Table 3 | Content Row 2 of Table 3 |
+------------------------------+--------------------------+
| Descriptive Row n of Table 3 | Content Row n of Table 3 |
+------------------------------+--------------------------+
```

I would like to use this for a flexible layout for devices with different screen sizes. Using float:left for the tables I get them wrapped but I have not found a way to hide the descriptive column between the tables.